# How to force HTML input file chooser to give the original file name in Ionic(Android)?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, filechooser

I am using HTML `input` for choosing file in my Ionic3/Angular application. I am using below code:

**// in .html file**

```
<input #fileUpload type="file" name="myfile"(change)="onFileChoose($event)"/>
```

**// in .ts file**

```
onFileChoose($event): void {
    this.fileChooser.getFileInfo($event).then((result) => {
      this.fileName = result.fileName;
      this.fileData = this.sanitizeFileData(result.fileData);
      this.fileSize = result.fileSize;
      this.fileType = result.fileType;
    }, (error) => {
      this.helperProvider.createAlert('Alert', 'File is corrupted.');
    });
  }

 getFileInfo(event: Event): Promise<any> {

    let target = event && event.target;
    let files: Array<File> = target && target['files'];

    console.log(files[0].type);
    console.log(files[0].name);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (files && files.length) {
        files = Array.from(files);
        let fileName = files[0].name;
        let fileSize = files[0].size;
        let fileType = files[0].type;
        let fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = () => resolve({
          fileData: fileReader.result,
          fileName: fileName,
          fileSize: fileSize,
          fileType: fileType
        });

        fileReader.onerror = error => reject(error);

        fileReader.onabort = error => reject(error);

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
      }
    });
  }
```

This is working fine in `iOS` and `Browser`. Both, in android and browser, i could get the original name, size and type of the file. But the problem occurs in **Android**.

**Scenario-1(Android):** When i choose an image file using the file chooser, i could get the original file name, size and type of the file.

**Scenario-2(Android):** When i choose a file other than image file like **.pdf**,**.doc** etc, i could not get the original file name and the type of the file. Suppose, i have choosen a file name "**sample.pdf**", but after i chose the file, i get the file name as a random number like *45675* and ***most importantly the file type, i got is empty***.

Then, i researched in stackoverflow and saw these links ([**link1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606003/file-upload-using-file-input-with-ionic-selection-of-file-using-native-file-bro) and **[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376005/android-file-upload-wrong-file-name-native-browser)**). It may be a security issue for android.

There is an [ionic-native/file-chooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/) library but it is only for **android platform**.

Is there any way to force android to give the original file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not give the original file name and file type using the above approach of mine and it is a security issue from android. So, i had to make below solution for retrieving the correct file name, file type, file size and the file data in base64.

You will need below four plugins:

1. [FileChooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/)
2. [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)
3. [FilePath](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/)
4. [Base64](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/)

**FileChooserAndroidProvider:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {File, FileEntry, IFile} from "@ionic-native/file";
import {Base64} from "@ionic-native/base64";
import {FilePath} from "@ionic-native/file-path";
import {FileChooser} from "@ionic-native/file-chooser";


@Injectable()
export class FileChooserAndroidProvider {

  constructor(private base64: Base64, private filePath: FilePath, private file: File, private fileChooser: FileChooser) {
  }

  getFileInfo(): Promise<any> {
    return this.fileChooser.open().then((fileURI) => {
      return this.filePath.resolveNativePath(fileURI).then((filePath) => {
        return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(filePath).then((fileEntry: FileEntry) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fileEntry.file(meta => resolve(meta), error => reject(error));
          });
        }).then((fileMeta: IFile) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return this.base64.encodeFile(filePath).then((base64Data) => {
              resolve({
                fileData: base64Data,
                fileName: fileMeta.name,
                fileSize: fileMeta.size,
                fileType: fileMeta.type
              })
            }).catch((error) => {
              reject(error);
            })
          })
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**FileChooserAndroidProviderModule:**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Base64} from "@ionic-native/base64";
import {FileChooser} from "@ionic-native/file-chooser";
import {FilePath} from "@ionic-native/file-path";
import {File} from "@ionic-native/file";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    FileChooser,
    File,
    FilePath,
    Base64
  ]
})
export class FileChooserAndroidProviderModule {
}
```

**SamplePage:**

```
constructor(private fileChooserAndroid: FileChooserAndroidProvider){}

  uploadFileForAndroid(): void {
    this.fileChooserAndroid.getFileInfo().then((result) => {
      this.fileName = result.fileName;
      this.fileData = this.sanitizeFileData(result.fileData);
      this.fileSize = result.fileSize;
      this.fileType = result.fileType;
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.helperProvider.createAlert('Alert', 'File can not be uploaded.');
    });
  }
```

**SamplePageModule:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SamplePage
  ],
  imports: [
    FileChooserAndroidProviderModule
  ],
  providers: [
    FileChooserAndroidProvider
  ]
})
export class SamplePageModule {
}
```